# SQLAlchemy execute: How to hand over parameters for subquery

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to execute a SQL Statement (PostgreSQL) like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
SET min_val = sub_q.min_val
FROM (SELECT min(value) as min_val FROM table2 WHERE table2.type = 2) sub_q
WHERE t1.person = 5
```

with the function sqlalchemy.execute and hand over the parameter in a save way like this:

```
sql_stmt = """UPDATE table1 t1 
              SET min_val = sub_q.min_val
              FROM (SELECT min(value) as min_val FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.type = %(table2.type)s sub_q
              WHERE t1.person = %(t1.person)s
           """
params = {
          "t2.type": 2,
          "t1.person": 5
         }
execute(sql_stmt, params)
```

For a normal query this method works, but for an nested query I got the error message:

> psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "%" LINE 3: ...
> WHERE t2.type = %(table2.type)s...

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think your SQL itself is missing a `)`.  `(SELECT min(value) as min_val FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.type = %(table2.type)s >)< sub_q`.

It will be easier in the long run to setup full sqlalchemy tables but if you cannot do that then you should try to use bind params and wrapping your text in `text()` like below:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    text,
    bindparam,
)
from sqlalchemy import Integer

sql_stmt = text("""UPDATE table1 t1
              SET min_val = sub_q.min_val
              FROM (SELECT min(value) as min_val FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.type = :type) sub_q
              WHERE t1.person = :person""")
sql_stmt = sql_stmt.bindparams(
    bindparam("type", type_=Integer),
    bindparam("person", type_=Integer))
session.execute(sql_stmt, {"type": 2, "person": 1})
session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes you're right, in this example I forgot a ')', but I rechecked my SQL Statement, it seems to be right.